# Unable to get the redirecting server's details

Tags: php, redirect

I am having a redirect to my server B from some different server A. 
PFB the redirection response -

http://screencloud.net/v/sn1w

while the request to my server appears to be -

http://screencloud.net/v/81KP

I am not sure how can I get the details of server A who made the redirection to my server. I have tried following php script but no success so far -

```
<?php

var_dump($_SERVER);

echo "<br/><br/><br/>";

var_dump($_REQUEST);

echo "<br/><br/><br/>";

var_dump($_ENV);

?>
```

I can't see any useful parameter which give some details about server A.

Please let me know if any option available?

Thanks in advance